# Validation of SimpleTextArea in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm new to Dojo and I have to eliminate/shouldn't allow the user to enter HTML tags in a text area. I tried a few but didn't work. Later I tried to get the content out of HTML tags but even that didn't work. Could you please help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.byId("comments").innerHTML = dojo.replace("<[^>]*>", "");
  });
</script>

<div id="comments" name="comments" dojoType="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea" maxLength="900" style="width: 98%; padding-right: 4px; font-size: 1.2em;" aria-required="true" title="<fmt:message key="widget.content2" />"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old syntax for Dojo; if you're new - best if you start learning the new style.

Hope the below helps.

```js
require([
  'dojo/ready',
  'dojo/on',
  'dojo/parser',
  'dijit/registry',
  'dijit/form/SimpleTextarea'
], function(ready, on, parser, registry){
  ready(function(){
    parser.parse().then(function(){
      var comments = registry.byId('comments')
      on(comments, 'keyup', function(){
        var value = comments.get('value')
        comments.set('value', value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''))
      })
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#comments {
  width: 98%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

<div id="comments" name="comments" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea" maxLength="900" aria-required="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Lewis. Currently we are using 1.6.0 version of Dojo. When I added the above code snippet that function isn't being called and I wasn't able to strip html tags.

Comment: Yes, the above code uses the newer AMD syntax which won't work with Dojo 1.6.0.  I'm not familiar with 1.6.0 I'm afraid - I'm not sure how much of my answer is reusable.  If I can convert it easily, I'll post under a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.ready(function(){
var value = dojo.byId("comments").get('value')
        dojo.byId("comments").set('value', value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''))

      });
    </script>

    <div id="comments" name="comments" dojoType="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea" maxLength="900" style="width: 98%; padding-right: 4px; font-size: 1.2em;" aria-required="true" title="<fmt:message key="widget.content2" />"></div>
```

But you should start using a newer version of dojo as it has several good features. Thanks Lewis for the initial answer.

ok here is the jsfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/meesa41q/10/

Comment: Thank you Manjunatha... I have a input as <HTML>
 <SCRIPT>alert("hello")</SCRIPT>
</HTML> and expecting an output to remove the tags and println the content in the textarea but without the above code, thats not happening. I read that replace will replace all the content but it is not happening.. could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my last post, but using 1.6.0

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.SimpleTextarea");
dojo.ready(function(){
  var comments = dijit.registry.byId('comments')
  dojo.connect(comments, 'onKeyUp', function(){
    var value = comments.get('value')
    comments.set('value', value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''))
  })
});
```

```css
#comments {
  width: 98%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.js' djConfig='parseOnLoad: true'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/dijit.js'></script>

<div id="comments" name="comments" dojoType="dijit.form.SimpleTextarea" maxLength="900" aria-required="true"></div>
```